# Qt: how to set main window's initial position?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I think the normally window manager determines the initial position of the QMainWindow position on the desk top. I want to set the initial position myself. How is this done with Qt on Windows?

Comment: Can people who answer this question tell me this : How do I have the window remember its old position but return to the monitor if that position puts the window off screen?

Comment: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/geometry.html scroll down to "Restoring a window's geometry"

Answer (score 25):

You can restore the window geometry with [restoreGeometry()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#restoreGeometry), and the state of docked elements with [restoreState()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#restoreState), during the construction of your MainWindow...

```
    QSettings settings("yourcompany", "yourapp");

    restoreGeometry(settings.value("geometry").toByteArray());
    restoreState(settings.value("state").toByteArray(),YOUR_UI_VERSION);
```

Then, if you override [closeEvent()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent), you can save the state as follows:

```
    QSettings settings("yourcompany", "yourapp");

    settings.setValue("geometry", saveGeometry());
    settings.setValue("state", saveState(YOUR_UI_VERSION));
```

YOUR_UI_VERSION is a constant you should increment when your UI changes significantly to prevent attempts to restore an invalid state.

Comment: +1: I had a hunch that something like that existed, but didn't know exactly how...

Answer (score 6):

I believe you're looking for [setGeometry](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayoutitem.html#setGeometry).

Comment: Convenience link for the most recent version of Qt: http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qlayoutitem.html#setGeometry