# Geometry of the main window in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt Creator, when I construct the main window of the application using form `mainwindow.ui`, fields `X` and `Y` of the `geometry` property are inactive and the window appears in some default position (I guess, the OS decides how to place the window most conveniently). But when I set geometry from code using method `setGeometry`, I am obliged to set fixed position in pixels from the left top corner of the screen, which is not the same thing.

I understand, that we can get the size of the screen and the size of the window so we can place the window where ever we want, but in this case the position will still be predetermined. My question is how to trigger that option, which is set by default when we use forms?

Comment: What is your question again? What are you trying to do? Right now you're describing two different things, but you haven't said why.

Comment: It may be useful: [Qt: how to set main window's initial position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866970/qt-how-to-set-main-windows-initial-position)

Comment: @KubaOber, my question is how to set geometry for the main window in code, so the OS desides where to places it. It's the default way when we use forms.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Setting the geometry (*position* and *size*) implies that you decide where the window is, not the OS. The two are mutually exclusive. Were you wishing to asked how to change the window size only? You can set a `QWidget`'s minimum size, and you can also `resize` it. Please clarify.

Comment: @KubaOber, yes, that's what I meant: how to set main window size and leave the OS priority in placing this window. Clearly, geometry is not a solution. Sorry for my poor phrasing. Resize works perfectly, thanks! If you are going to post an answer, could you please also specify how to control the fact that the window is placed by OS. Is there any flag? Otherwise, after I set geometry, how can I "unset" it? Is there a way back to default window placing?

Comment: I don't think that Qt exposes a way to do it. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11838077/1329652) for a platform-specific way of doing it on Windows, for example.

Comment: @KubaOber, thanks, that's helpfull